# Copying multiple lines in mail.Body in VB

Tags: email, vba

I wanted to add multiple lines to the body of a mail using VB. Below the code for openining and formatting the mail:

```
With Workbooks("HEelo world.xlsx").Worksheets("Hello")
    mail.To = .Range(.Range("F:F").Find("Address1").Address).Offset(0, 1)
    mail.Cc = .Range(.Range("F:F").Find("Address2").Address).Offset(0, 1)
    mail.Subject = .Range(.Range("F:F").Find("Object").Address).Offset(0, 1)
    mail.Body = .Range(.Range("F:F").Find("Body").Address).Offset(0, 1)
    mail.Body = ....
End With
```

What is the correct syntax for adding multiple lines?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you are searching the F:F column range using Find("<name>") rather than a specific cell. What sort of setup is your sheet in? Knowing this might make it easier or more efficient. Your answer below however works just fine for separating the mail object body with Carriage returns.

Comment: Always adding and replacing cells in column F, therefore specifying a cell would be not a good idea. As far as your comment on the answer what do you mean with Carriage returns?

Comment: Carriage return is the name give  to a new line character. In vb this is specified with the vb constant vbCr or vbCrLf (the Cr being carriage return and Lf to specify it is left justified on the next line.) I believe we can make the code much neater using cell Names. Does the body have to be in 4 different cells?

Comment: The text I wanted to put in the mail body is a list of statistics

Comment: You can name cells making them easier to reference. The names will move along with the cells you add so ranges should stay the same. You can then itterate through this range to add multiple lines to the body.

Comment: I have added my own answer below for you to check out.

Answer (score 1):

I found this which should work:

```
Dim strBody As String
        strBody = .Range(.Range("B:B").Find("text1").Address).Offset(0, 1) & vbCrLf _
        & .Range(.Range("B:B").Find("text2").Address).Offset(0, 1) & vbCrLf _
        & .Range(.Range("B:B").Find("text3").Address).Offset(0, 1) & vbCrLf _
        & .Range(.Range("B:B").Find("text4").Address).Offset(0, 1) & vbCrLf 
mail.Body = strBody
```

Answer (score 1):

[Dummies Guide to naming Excel ranges](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-name-a-cell-or-range-in-excel-2010.html)

Use the link I've provided to learn how to modify a range to have a *Name*. You can target a range as a named reference in your vba. For this example we have called the cell range (eg.B4:B8) that contains the value for the mail body "BodyValue"

```
Dim strBody As String
    strBody = ""
    For Each cl in Range("BodyValue").Cells
        strBody = cl.Value & vbCrLf
    Next
mail.Body = strBody
```

You can do this for all parts used in your email as well so instead of using an Offset, name your cells or ranges and reference the names in your VBA. This will also avoid errors occuring if you add a row or column in any part of your sheet as named cells keep their name independant of changes to their address in the sheet.